# Laravel: PHP Fileinfo extension to use Intervention Image message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi on my localhost i can upload images perfect with Image Intervention. On my server i can't the say: **Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image**. I change my PHP Version to 5.3.29 before are in 5.6. I enable File Info but still not working. After upload i delete vendor and i run

> composer install

and

> composer dump-autoload

and later i upload it to my server but the problem continues. 
Here my composer.json file:

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html":"*", 
        "laracasts/flash": "^2.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
        "cviebrock/image-validator": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
```

Some one can help me here? Thanks :)

Comment: could you check if there is `fileinfo` listed when running `php -m` in your terminal?

Comment: @Skysplit Let me try it.

Comment: @Skysplit They return this: `[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
ionCube Loader
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
pspell
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
SQLite
sqlite3
standard
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend Guard Loader
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend Guard Loader
the ionCube PHP Loader`

Comment: I assume it's from your server, not localhost. If so, then it is pretty weird. Try finding `extension=php_fileinfo` in `php.ini` on your server. If it has `;` on the beginning of the line, try removing it and restart php/reload configuration.

Comment: @Skysplit On /usr/local/lib/php.ini i can't find that extension. You know why? Is the correct php.ini file? Thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo phpenmod fileinfo`.

Comment: @Skysplit says: sudo: phpenmod: command not found